# Navigate from one page to another on Button click

Tags: javascript, html, react-router, router

Hey I'm trying to make a Student Management System, where I made a Login page,Signup and a Dashboard page.
Now, while clicking a Button 'Fill Details' from my Dashboard page I need to navigate to another page input.js (Which is actually a separate project). I'll link my code below. Please help me to make it!

```
//input.js
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import web3 from './web3';
    import ipfs from './ipfs';
    import storehash from './storehash';
    import { Button } from 'reactstrap';


    class MyComponent extends Component {
      state = {      
        ipfsHash:null,      
        buffer:'',      
        ethAddress:'',      
        transactionHash:'',      
        txReceipt: ''    
      };


      //Take file input from user
      captureFile =(event) => {event.stopPropagation() 
        event.preventDefault() 
        const file = event.target.files[0] 
        let reader = new window.FileReader() 
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file) 
        reader.onloadend = () => this.convertToBuffer(reader) };


      //Convert the file to buffer to store on IPFS 
          convertToBuffer = async(reader) => {

      //file is converted to a buffer for upload to IPFS        
          const buffer = await Buffer.from(reader.result);   

      //set this buffer-using es6 syntax        
           this.setState({buffer});};

      //ES6 async 
        functiononClick = async () => {try{this.setState({blockNumber:"waiting.."});        
        this.setState({gasUsed:"waiting..."});
        await web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(this.state.transactionHash, (err, txReceipt)=>{          
          console.log(err,txReceipt);          
          this.setState({txReceipt});        
        });    
      }

      catch(error){      
        console.log(error);   
       }}


       onSubmit = async (event) => {      
         event.preventDefault();

         //bring in user's metamask account address      
         const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();   

         //obtain contract address from storehash.js      
         const ethAddress= await storehash.options.address;      
         this.setState({ethAddress});    

         //save document to IPFS,return its hash#, and set hash# to state      
         await ipfs.add(this.state.buffer, (err, ipfsHash) => {        
           console.log(err,ipfsHash);        

           //setState by setting ipfsHash to ipfsHash[0].hash        
           this.setState({ ipfsHash:ipfsHash[0].hash });       
           
           
           // call Ethereum contract method "sendHash" and .send IPFS hash to etheruem contract       
          //return the transaction hash from the ethereum contract        
          storehash.methods.sendhash(this.state.ipfsHash).send({          
            from: accounts[0]        
          }, 
            (error, transactionHash) => {          
            console.log(transactionHash);          
            this.setState({transactionHash});        
          });  

          

        })    
      };


      render() {
        return (        
        <div className="App">          
        <header className="App-header">  
        <h1>EduDecentro</h1>          
        </header>

        <hr/>
        <grid>          
          <h5> Choose Transcript file  </h5>          
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>            
          <input              
          type = "file"              
          onChange = {this.captureFile}            
          />             
          <Button             
          bsStyle="primary"             
          type="submit">             
          Send it             
          </Button> 
          </form>
          <tbody>                 
             <tr>                   
               <td>IPFS Hash</td>                   
                <td> : </td>                    
                <td>{this.state.ipfsHash1}</td>                  
                </tr>
          </tbody>
          

          <h5> Choose Certificate-1 file  </h5>          
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>            
          <input              
          type = "file"              
          onChange = {this.captureFile}            
          />             
          <Button             
          bsStyle="primary"             
          type="submit">             
          Send it             
          </Button> 
          </form>
          <tbody>                 
             <tr>                   
               <td>IPFS Hash</td>                   
                <td> : </td>                    
                <td>{this.state.ipfsHash2}</td>                  
                </tr>
          </tbody>

          <h5> Choose Certificate-2 file  </h5>          
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>            
          <input              
          type = "file"              
          onChange = {this.captureFile}            
          />             
          <Button             
          bsStyle="primary"             
          type="submit">             
          Send it             
          </Button> 
          </form>

          <h5> Choose Resume file  </h5>          
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>            
          <input              
          type = "file"              
          onChange = {this.captureFile}            
          />             
          <Button             
          bsStyle="primary"             
          type="submit">             
          Send it             
          </Button> 
          

          </form><hr/> 
          </grid>     
        </div>      
       );    
    }}

     export default MyComponent;






    



    import React from 'react';


    import {Link } from "react-router-dom";

     
    function Dashboard(props) {
     
      // handle click event of logout button
      const handleLogout = () => {    
        props.history.push('/Sign-in');
      }

      
     
      return (
        <div>
          Welcome User!<br /><br />
          <Link to="/input"><button>
                  Fill Details 
                </button>
                </Link>

          <input type="button" onClick={handleLogout} value="Logout" />
        </div>
      );
    }
     
    export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: use Redirect Component  from from 'react-router-dom'

Comment: can you please elaborate!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You're more likely to receive a helpful answer if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to add event listener for your `Fill Details` button, you don't need to wrap it into the `Link` component. Here is the example:

```
<button onClick={() => window.location.href = 'YOUR_LINK_TO_ANOTHER_APP' }>
  Fill Details 
</button>
```

Comment: Actually I've both apps in separate folder, I need the Dashboard page navigate to another react app(which is a separate folder). How do I make that? <button onClick={() => window.location.href = 'YOUR_LINK_TO_ANOTHER_APP' }>
  Fill Details 
</button> Will this work in that case too?  Or how can I combine both apps to single app! Single app would be better.please suggest some idea

Comment: Did you try my approach?

Comment: What link did you put in ```window.location.href```?

Comment: that's, '/input' .

Comment: if you want to navigate to another application, the URL must be absolute like  ```www.google.com```. Inserting just ```/input``` you are trying to navigate to page that inside your first app but it is not. Your second app must deployed somewhere or at least be running on local server

Comment: If I run the second app on local server, what is the link I should give?

Comment: The link you see in browser when you open the second app.

Comment: Is there any way to merge both apps? Bring the components of second app into first app?

Comment: You can make one app from two manually (copy + paste). Or you can dive into micro frontend pattern that gives an opportunity to keep different apps as one.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onClick="window.location.href='Second_App_Page_Link';">Click Here
</button>
```

Comment: Actually I've both apps in separate folder, I need the Dashboard page navigate to another react app(which is a separate folder). How do I make that? <button onClick={() => window.location.href = 'YOUR_LINK_TO_ANOTHER_APP' }> Fill Details </button> Will this work in that case too? Or how can I combine both apps to single app! Single app would be better.please suggest some idea

Comment: Do you mean you have 2 apps in one project? Or you have 2 apps that are not connected at all?

Comment: They are not connected. Both are separate apps created using create-react-app